# MySQL: Does the default value checked by the `CHECK` constraint?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema, best-practices

Say I have the following schema, would the default value `https://sample.com` be checked by the `CHECK (Website LIKE "https://%")`?

```
CREATE TABLE Company (
    AccountID varchar(25),
    Name varchar(20)        NOT NULL,
    Website varchar(255)    DEFAULT 'https://sample.com',
    Categories varchar(255) NOT NULL
                            DEFAULT '[]',
    PRIMARY KEY(AccountID),
    
    CHECK                   (CHAR_LENGTH(AccountID) BETWEEN 4 AND 25),
    CHECK                   (CHAR_LENGTH(Name) BETWEEN 2 AND 20),
    CHECK                   (Website LIKE "https://%")
);
```

Comment: No, default value in table definition is not checked. Only the value to be written (either assigned by default or provided explicitly) is checked. This check is performed after BEFORE triggers execution (if exists).

Comment: See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1e4bfb97083bd55469dadfa59de5bc7d)

Comment: Se https://elephantdolphin.blogspot.com/2021/04/default-values-check-constraint-and.html for a quick example and how to test

Answer (score 0):

Checking default value doesn't make sense, as you have declared the static value which must be correct only. But the values which are going to be inserted manually are not checked using `CHECK` constrainst.

```
CREATE TABLE Company (
    AccountID varchar(25),
    Name varchar(20)        NOT NULL,
    Website varchar(255)    DEFAULT 'https://sample.com',
    Categories varchar(255) NOT NULL
                            DEFAULT '[]',
    PRIMARY KEY(AccountID),
    
    CHECK                   (CHAR_LENGTH(AccountID) BETWEEN 4 AND 25),
    CHECK                   (CHAR_LENGTH(Name) BETWEEN 2 AND 20),
    CHECK                   (Website LIKE "https://%")
);
```

See here : the value like  hps://sdfs.com , asdfas://sdfs.com are not supposed to insert but they are inserted successfully.

```
insert into Company(ACCOUNTID , Name )  values ('12','asdf');
insert into Company(ACCOUNTID , Name , Website)  values ('13','asdf',"hps://sdfs.com");
insert into Company(ACCOUNTID , Name , Website)  values ('1','asdf4',"asdfas://sdfs.com");
```

```
select * from Company ; 

Output : 

# AccountID, Name, Website, Categories
1, asdf4, asdfas://sdfs.com, []
12, asdf, https://sample.com, []
13, asdf, hps://sdfs.com, []
```

Apart from using `CHECK` constraint I would suggest to use Triggers for validating this values or using JAVASCRIPT to valid this values.